# What's the difference with Node js and XAMPP

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, http, xampp

I am reading a book *"Real-Time Communication with WebRTC"*, it says:

> Node.js is an extremely powerful software platform that allows users
>   to easily build scalable server-side applications with JavaScript. It
>   is based on a single-threaded event loop management process making use
>   of nonblocking I/O. The library provides a built-in HTTP server
>   implementation, making it independent from third-party software
>   components. With Node.js, it is really easy for the programmer to
>   implement a high-performance HTTP server with customized behavior with
>   just a few lines of code.

I already use XAMMP as a local HTTP server, why do i need Node.js? What's the difference with Node js and XAMPP? I am new to Node.js stuff.

Answer (score 6):

XAMPP and Node.js are completely different:

XAMPP is a distribution consisting of Apache, MySQL and PHP. So you are using Apache as your web server.

Node.js is a Javascript framework. You could build you own web server with Node.js

Comment: and Xampp runs PHP on the server side while node runs javascript on the server.